# Unmapping the global mappings on a per-buffer basis

Tags: key-bindings, global-command, terminal-buffer

I have the following mapping in `tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>` init.conf  to exit insert mode while in the terminal. 
In certain terminal buffers I would like to not have that global mapping applied.

The command `:tunmap <buffer> <Esc>` doesn't effect globally set mappings.

The command `:tunmap <buffer>` will remove the mapping for all buffers.

Is there a way to not apply global config to a certain buffer only?

Comment: Would that work? `tnoremap <buffer> <ESC> <ESC>`?

Comment: @Ralf Yes! Just phrase it please as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could overwrite the mapping by a buffer-local mapping. Just map `<ESC>` to `<ESC>`:

```
tnoremap <buffer> <ESC> <ESC>
```